# Adding Name to tooltip in altair-python

Tags: python, tooltip, altair

I'm trying to add movie title names and rating to a violin plot so when you scroll it shows both name and rating. My code is as follows:

```
import altair as alt

plot = alt.Chart(data_trim).transform_density(
    'Rate',
    as_=['Rate', 'density'],
    extent=[0, 10],
    groupby=['Genre_rename']
).mark_area(orient='horizontal').encode(
    y='Rate:Q',
    color=alt.Color("Genre_rename", scale = alt.Scale(scheme = "rainbow")),
    x=alt.X(
        'density:Q',
        stack='center',
        impute=None,
        title=None,
        axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, values=[0],grid=True, ticks=True),
    ),    
    column=alt.Column(
        'Genre_rename:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            titleOrient='bottom',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelPadding=0,
        )
    ),
        tooltip=["Rate", "Name"]
).properties(
    width=100
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
plot
```

But when I do this it shows Name:undefined for all of the points. I've tried also using:

```
tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('data_trim.Name:N', title='Name')]
```

But that also shows undefined. I can't remember the other way I tried, but I got an error saying 'Name' is not type 'object', but when I used dtypes to check, Name is type object. Any ideas on how to get the names to display?

Answer (score 0):

If it says "Undefined" you're likely using a column name that does not exist in your data set. It is hard to tell without knowing what `data_trim` looks like in your code. Here is a complete example with some sample data and a working tooltip:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.cars()).transform_density(
    'Miles_per_Gallon',
    as_=['Miles_per_Gallon', 'density'],
    extent=[5, 50],
    groupby=['Origin']
).mark_area(orient='horizontal').encode(
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N',
    tooltip=['Origin'],
    x=alt.X(
        'density:Q',
        stack='center',
        impute=None,
        title=None,
        axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, values=[0],grid=False, ticks=True),
    ),
    column=alt.Column(
        'Origin:N',
        header=alt.Header(
            titleOrient='bottom',
            labelOrient='bottom',
            labelPadding=0,
        ),
    )
).properties(
    width=100
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```